# ANTLR4 Visitor subtree check

Tags: antlr, visitor-pattern, antlr4

I have an Antlr4 question.  Given the grammar excerpt below. What is the correct approach to testing for the existence of the optional `actualParameters` subtree within a visitor?

I have tried the getChildCount method of the procedureCallStatement context. I've also tested for a null actualParameters parameter on the context.

I do not want to visit the actualParameters subtree if it does not exist.  Doing so causes an exception.

Thank you!

Kelvin Johnson

```
program : statement (';' statement)* ';'?;

statement : CALLPREFIX('(' actualParameters? ')')?  #procedureCallStatement;

actualParameters : expressionStatement (';' expressionStatement)* ;

expressionStatement : '(' expressionStatement ')'  #parensExpression
| IDENT'[' expressionStatement ']' #subscript
...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The automatically-generated context method `ProcedureCallStatementContext.actualParameters()` will return the `ActualParametersContext` if one was parsed, otherwise it will return `null`.

You might make use of it in a visitor like this:

```
public T VisitProcedureCallStatement(ProcedureCallStatementContext ctx) {
    if (ctx.actualParameters() != null) {
        // do something here
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks 280Z28 :)  This is what I was trying to do; test the context against null but this technique was failing. Turns out I had a typo. I just tried again and it is working.  Computers can be so annoying.  They only do what you tell them!!

Answer (score 1):

Either call ctx.getActualParameters() or label it

```
statement : CALLPREFIX('(' args=actualParameters? ')')?  #procedureCallStatement;
```

and then use ctx.getArgs()

Comment: Hello. I have been using ctx.actualParameters.  I notice that it was not gernerated with the get prefix.